# Permission denied on opencart

Tags: php, module, opencart

I was trying to create a payment module for opencart. When i tried to save the details in settings page, it's giving me the error "Permission Denied!" even though I was logged in as a administrator.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set yourself with permissions. Go to

```
SYSTEM > USERS > USER GROUPS
```

in the admin panel, click `EDIT` next to your user group, then make sure the boxes are checked next to `payment/your-payment-name-here` (or just click `Select All` Under both boxes)

Comment: And what if that page is also denied? What's a top admin to do after he has denied himself access to the "access" page?

Comment: @Pacerier - Create a proper question as this isn't the place to ask this, and I can provide you with the answer on how to do this

Comment: Ok, it's done: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart/77562#77562

Comment: @Pacerier - You will need to make a question on StackOverflow for me to be able to answer it using a full answer and not just the comments system. Area 51 doesn't allow this