# permission denied in creation of menu in opencart

Tags: opencart

I was trying to create a header menu for opencart. When i tried to make menu in smenu page, it's giving me the error "Permission Denied!" even though I was logged in as a administrator. I used a extension custom header menu and also install vqmod as per method of installation of this extension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permission denied on opencart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187930/permission-denied-on-opencart)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"Permission Denied!"** happens when file is not present or you do not have read/write over the file

Goto you `user->usergroups` make selection again

- Access Permission: Select All
- Modify Permission: Select All

hope that will solve your problem